# How to scroll a scrollable layout in the Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've imported my Project form Eclipse into Android Studio and I can't find the way to scroll my scrollable layout in the program (of course I am sure it is scrollable - I can scroll in the Eclipse and on a device).

[image: can't scroll scrollable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this change set: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/61089/ , there is a fix for this coming soon. I'd hazard a guess you'll see the fix in 0.1.7.

Comment: Thanks, I've reported this last week and they will fix it because of this report, but your answer is perfectly good.

Answer (score 0):

The fix bkromhout mentioned only works if the ScrollView is the root of the layout. I had put mine on top of the default RelativeLayout and had to manually fix that in the XML before the GUI would give me the full view. I hope this helps others who did the same.

Comment: It has been Fix or not...now i sill cannot scroll in Android Studio 2.0 Preview 4